# Every proper subgroup of a simple group containing an order 45 element has an index of at least 14

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, simple-groups

> Every proper subgroup of a simple group containing an order $45$ element has an index of at least $14$.

So far I've supposed that $G$ is a simple group with an element of order $45$. Then $45$ divides the order of $G$. Also, suppose there's a proper subgroup $N$ with index $n$. Then then there's a mapping $\phi:G\rightarrow S_n$. Note that $G$ is simple so the kernel is trivial and this map is injective. Thus $|G|=|\text{Im}(\phi)|$. Since the image is a subgroup of $S_n$, $|\text{Im}(\phi)|$ divides $|S_n|=n!$. Ultimately, $45$ divides $n!$, but I think this shows that $n\geq 6$, not $14$. How can I make the jump to $14$? Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: 9+5=14...

Comment: Slightly different hint: $45$ divides $6!$, but does $S_6$ contain an element of order $45$?

Comment: That makes so much sense! Thank you both! Since the permutation orders are the lcm of cycle lengths, n has to be 14 or greater.

Comment: For any proper subgroup $H$ of $G$, we need to show $|G|/|H|\ge 14$, $5+9=14$, so it has to be at least $|S_{14}|$, and $G$ is isomorphic to some subgroup of $|S_{14}|$. But how does it help with $|G|/|H|\ge 14$? @SteveD